# Type of a rest array in a destructured object

Tags: typescript, flowtype

How do I annotate `c` here to be an optional array of any type?

```
const a = ({ b, ...c }: { b: string, c: ? }) => null
```

Comment: When you say "optional", what do you mean? `c` is always going to be an object. It may be empty (if `a` is called with an object with no own properties other than `b`), but it's always going to be an object.

Comment: True, empty is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that's property destructuring, it won't be an array, it'll be an `object`:

```
const a = ({ b, ...c }: { b: string, c: object}) => null;
```

Live non-TypeScript example:

```js
const a = ({ b, ...c }) => {
  console.log("typeof c:", typeof c);                 // true
  console.log("Array.isArray(c):", Array.isArray(c)); // false
  console.log(JSON.stringify(c));                     // '{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3}'
};
a({x: 1, y: 2, z: 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you described, an optional array of any type: `c?: Array<any>`

```js
const a = ({b, c}: { b: string, c?: Array<any> }): void => null
```

Example:

```js
const a = ({b, c}: { b: string, c?: Array<any> }): void => {
  console.log('b:', b)
  if (c instanceof Array) {
    for (let item of c) {
      console.log('c item:', item)
    }
  }
}

a({b: '1', c: [1]})
a({b: '1'})
```

`{b, c}:` is unpacking, `b` and `c` are both variables. `{b, ...c}:` is an illegal declaration.
.